# URL's not working on facebook tab

Tags: url

Bit of a strange issue here.

I have a group of social media icons that animate on hover however the url's they link to won't open when viewing them on the facebook tab they reside on.

The webpage the content is on opens the url's fine so the problem only appears to be when viewing it on the tab itself (plus also when viewing it in jsfiddle) that the link won't open.

Here's a jsfiddle so you can see the problem http://jsfiddle.net/dn6d4/8/

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk"><div class="fbook-hover social-slide"></div></a>
```

CSS

```
.fbook-hover {
background-image: url('https://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/images/smedia/fbook.png');
}
.social-slide {
height:270px;
width: 225px;
margin: 22px;
float: left;
-webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
transition: all ease 0.3s;
} 
.social-slide:hover {
background-position: 0px -270px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the Facebook icon in your jsfiddle gives a Javascript error:

`Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.uk/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'`

This is because http://google.co.uk redirects to https://google.co.uk, and Google don't allow their site to be displayed in an iframe on another site.

Facebook tabs are displayed in an iframe, so if the page that you are trying to link to with your Facebook icon also has the `X-Frame-Options` set to `SAMEORIGIN` then that would explain your problem.

There's more information about the `X-Frame-Options` header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

You won't be able to change the header on the site you're linking to, so I don't think it's possible to avoid this problem with your current setup.

I would suggest adding `target='_blank'` to your link so that it opens in a new tab.

Comment: target='_blank' solved the problem. I don't think I gave enough thought as to how the link would open ie. in another window or not, I certainly didn't want it displayed within the iframe that wasn't my intention. target='_blank' opens in another window so issue solved. thanks